# Filter HTTPEntity output to include new lines

Tags: java, android, io

I am using `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` for doing a multipart/form data POST to `HTTPURLConnection` to upload a file.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
String part1 = "\n{\"name\":\"test.txt\",\"creationTime\":1527023510389,\"fileUri\":\"/storage/test.txt\"}";
File file = new File("/storage/test.txt");

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addBinaryBody("data", part1.getBytes(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON, "data.txt")
                .addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN, filename)
                .setBoundary(boundaryString)
                .build();
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
entity.writeTo(os);
```

I see that the body is being posted as the following.

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="metadata.txt"
Content-Type: application/json 
{"name":"test.txt","creationTime":1527023510389,"fileUri":"/storage/test.txt"}
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
test file contents
--BOUNDARY--
```

The problem is that the server requires a new line between the `Content-Type` and the contents of the first part. I've tried adding extra `"\n"` to the beginning contents (as seen but it gets erased when using `HttpEntity.writeto()`.

The output that I want is the following:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="metadata.txt"
Content-Type: application/json 

{"name":"test.txt","creationTime":1527023510389,"fileUri":"/storage/test.txt"}
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

test file contents
--BOUNDARY--
```

I attempted to modify rewriting the output but not sure if this is the best way to do it by storing in a temporary file. The files I will be working with will be up to 20mb if that makes any difference.

```
entity.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("file.tmp"));

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.tmp"));
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
String str;
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.println(str);
    if (str.contains("Content-Type: ")) {
        writer.println("\n");
    }
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();

if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    // It's failing when accessing the above method
}
```

I tried running the above code and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state: 2
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:234)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:1156)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:976)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:509)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:567)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `HttpEntity.writeTo` method is putting the necessary new lines but when I was printing the output to `System.out`, Android Studio's Logcat does not show plain new lines. I confirmed this by opening the `file.tmp` I was creating above and it had the proper new lines in there. It looks like there's some other error with the request since the body is valid for the server.

EDIT: Found the error in my request. I wasn't setting the Content-Type (I think I erased it while deleting some other code). I ended up using this to set the content type.

```
conn.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
```